# Controller class is not getting provoked in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa

Spring MVC Controller class is not working and throwing 404.

In application I created an entity and added all the credentials of my MS-SQL database. However, after staring the app and hitting the submit button the app is landed to 404 and controller is not provoked and entity is not created as well.

index.jsp is as follows:

```
 <form action = "/save" method = "post">
     ID: <input type = "text" name = "uid">
     <br />
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
  </form>
```

Controller class is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDao empDao;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(Employee emp){
        System.out.println("Here");
        empDao.saveEmployee(emp);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

The Entity Class:

```
Entity
@Table(name="employee")

public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int uid;
    private String name;
}
```

The context class:

```
@Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=cruddb11;integratedsecurity=true");
        ds.setUsername("ABCD");
        ds.setPassword("00000");

        return ds;
    }
```

The Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.websparrow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-fetch-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Hibernate Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Alpha5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring mvc dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring jdbc dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql databse connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Just adding some dependencies and code, doesn't automatically start the spring `DispatcherServlet`. If you don't have a `web.xml` or `WebApplicationInitializer`in your project nothing will be started and basically the application is unavailable. Another thing you are mixing hibernate jars from different versions (5.0 and 5.2) those should however match. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as you expect.

1.) This is not neccessary but helpful if you have more than one leading part in your url. Annotate your class with the @RequestMapping Annotation. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileoperations")    // Then you don't need the leading slash in the method
@Scope(value="session")
```

Use the second line if you are using sessions e.g. with Tomcat.

2.) The form only contains the variables uid and name so you must query them as parameters to work with in your controller.

3.) And also you must tell your controller to use the right Requestmethod. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String save(
        @RequestParam String uid,
        @RequestParam String name) {

      System.out.println("Here");

      // Maybe you should load the Employee first before updating it.
      Employee emp = this.empDao.readEmployee(name);
      if (emp != null) {
        emp.setUID(uid);
        emp.setName(name);
        this.empDao.saveEmployee(emp);
        return "success";
      } else {
        return "error: no employee here by that name";
      }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but this isn't work for me. my controller is still not getting hit. :(

Answer (score -1):

Change your `save` method signature to following, annotating Employee parameter with `@ModelAttribute`

```
@Autowired
public EmployeeDao empDao;

@RequestMapping("/save")
@ResponseBody
public String save(@ModelAttribute Employee emp){
    System.out.println("Here");
    empDao.saveEmployee(emp);
    return "success";
}
```

You had better change `@RequestMapping` to `@Post`.

Comment: I have tried that, Its not working. even console do not show anything.

Comment: @Usman can you show us the controller class declaration and the spring boot startup log.

Comment: I have already shown the controller class plus this ain't spring boot as you could see Its java based config app. and controller doesn't how anything.

Comment: `@RequestBody` is for receiving body encoded content (like json, xml). Here however a simple form submit is used and `@ModelAttribute` should be used (although that is also what is being implied).

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right. I haven't read to top part of the question carefully, I guess. Just by looking at his code snippet I thought it's a rest controller method since @Usman had annotated it with `@ResponseBody`, because we don't normally output row strings in MVC controller methods. Anyways, I'll change @RequestBody to @ModelAttribute in my answer just to avoid further downvotes :).